# bulk node creation based on number of files uploaded

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a module that enables the ability to automatically create nodes based on the number of files to be uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes? Nope, except for possibly rules or some other generic tools. On the other hand, you can try [File entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity):

> File entity provides interfaces for managing files. It also extends the core file entity, allowing files to be fieldable, grouped into types, viewed (using display modes) and formatted using field formatters. File entity integrates with a number of modules, exposing files to Views, Entity API, Token and more.

It claims to integrate with [Plupload](https://drupal.org/project/plupload), so it should be possible to use the two for bulk creation of file entities. Just not nodes, but node is only a kind of entity, and with module that adds fields to it, what's the difference, really?